# does .php files need the .php extension?

Tags: php, file

I am setting up a couple of PHP documents that include .cfg for configuration files, .tpl for template structure files, .dlf for document layout files, .dbh for database connections and so on.

Now they're called .tpl.php, .dlf.php etc. But do they need to have the .php extension as well?

If not are there any extensions I shouldn't be using? like .exe for executables.

Comment: How are you running the files? Are they being accessed at server level, or are you just using `include()` or `require()` to access their data?

Comment: No, it is just a convention. It should agree with configuration of other system components though. You are free to choose any extension, or no extension at all. Remember http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/

Comment: If they are used trough `include` or `require`, any extension will work.

Comment: I'm using `include` and `require` from .php documents like so: index.php requires `site.cfg.php`, `site.ini.php`, `site.tpl.php` and so on.. But for a better overview it would be nice to exclude the last .php-extension part. Some of these documents include other documents as well. And it's not only pure php code in those files. Some html as well. Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Hiding PHP on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php):

> Another tactic is to configure web servers such as apache to parse different filetypes through PHP, either with an `.htaccess` directive, or in the apache configuration file itself. You can then use misleading file extensions:
>
> ```
> # Make PHP code look like unknown types
> AddType application/x-httpd-php .bop .foo .133t
> ```

---

So you can add a `.htaccess` rule that would mean that your server treats `.tpl`, `.dlf` etc as if they were PHP files, like so:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .tpl .dlf .dbh
```

---

However, if you are just using `include` or `require`, it doesn't matter what extension you use:

```
include "inc/template.tpl";
require "inc/database.dbh";
require_once("inc/config.ext.php.url.tpl.cfg");
```

Comment: what if the included files consists of both php and html code? Would it still work as with the extension, og could I run into some problems along the way? The server is Linux...

Comment: It should be absolutely fine - just as if you were `include`-ing a regular `.PHP` file.

Answer (score 3):

You can change server config to enterpret other file extensions as PHP

In Apache you can add to this:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

if you `include` the files, then any extension will do:

in script.php:

```
include 'includes/foo.inc';
include 'inlcudes/bar.whatever';
```

will all work